# Find Minimum Value of Point within a buffer output as a point file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, buffer

I have a series of 30m buffers along a polyline (river). Within each buffer I have a series of points each point represents a 10m x 10m cell with an elevation value known as "Elev".

I want to find the one point with the minimum elev value within each buffer and output it as a point file. In a future geoprocessing set I'll like to snap this point back to the river.

ArcGIS 10.1, arcinfo license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom [Calculate Point Statistics toolbox](http://ianbroad.com/arcgis-toolbox-calculate-point-statistics-polygon-arcpy/) that basically does this. It loops through each polygon feature and finds the minimum, maximum, and average of the points within each polygon. However, instead of outputting the results to a point feature, it adds them to the polygon feature.

You could pretty easily change the script to do what you want.

[View the Source Code](http://ianbroad.com/download/script/CalculatePointStatistics.py)

Comment: Thank you Ian. I should easily be able to change your script to meet my needs. Thanks again.